# Standard procedure for geometric transformations

Tags: python, transformation, computational-geometry

I'm trying to build a very basic tool for a problem in mechanical engineering and need to do simple transformations of coordinates and vectors in euclidian space which include translations + rotations.

For example

- a component part with a local coordinate system (cs) is moved in respect to a world cs. I need to compute the new position of the (origin of) the local cs and its orientation.
- a vector is shifted and rotated in respect to a cs. Its new position has to be computed.

I'm aware of different concepts for doing these computations:

- Euler angles
- Quaternions
- Homogeneous coordinates

From my POV the use of homogeneous coordinates would be the simplest approach because it is possible to compute translations and rotations in one step.

Questions:

- What is the most common approach in programming to implement this kind of computations?
- Is there a python library which can handle these transformations? I found some smaller libraries like [transformations.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html) but I guess transformations like these are very very common and so I wonder if this isn't part of scipy or something like that.

After all i assume i'm searching for the wrong terms and would be glad if someone could provide a hint for further reading, code examples, libraries (especially for python).

Comment: generally there exists `numpy` which can give you matrix multiplication. So you just have to input the transformation matrix. `numpy` can inverse, transpose and do all kind of things with matrices.

Comment: What is a COS ?

Comment: what i meant was coordinate system. i just realized that the common abbreviation would be cs so i corrected that.

Comment: There is no common abbreviation for "coordinate system".

Comment: Anyway, it should be clear now.

Comment: Transformations are implemented with matrix operations, and because of that numpy is the best choice. Module transformations.py you mentioned is **very nice** numpy implementation. You can use that module or if you have special requests use that module as starting point of implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Use `numpy` and linear algebra to do the transformations as matrix multiplications